# Position image so that it's always positioned the same way no matter window width

Tags: css, position, css-position

I'm trying to position an image on my website so that it looks like it's paper clipped to the website content, in the outer skirt of the body block, like so:

[image]

I manage to get this positioning using the position: absolute; css attribute, and then position the image using top / right values. Problem is though that this only works for my home full screen (and others with same res of course), and as soon as I narrow down the window it looks like this:

[image]

The image is shifted inwards because my css tells it to. Has anyone got any idea of what CSS attribute I should use to have the image positioned at the same place no matter how wide the window is?

**EDIT:** This is the CSS that I solved it with using the input from George and Ed:

```
#picture-container {
            position: relative;
            max-width: 1px;
            max-height: 1px;
        }

        #image {
            position: absolute;
            right: -932px;
            top: -30px;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post some example code? The fix will be to add `position: relative` to your container, and then position the image relative to that.

Comment: @Ed-M Thanks Ed! Yea, I tried that. Problem was though that were the image was supposed to be left a big hole of an empty place holder. Do you know if I can specify that I don't want this place holder for relative positioning?

Comment: You'll need to apply `position: relative` to the container, and then use `position: absolute` on the image itself (taking it out of the document flow). Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/J5srJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be to add `position: relative` to your container (creating a new positioning context), and then position the image relative to that. Currently, you are positioning the `img` relative to the `body`.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/J5srJ/) that shows the difference that declaration makes, screenshot below.

[image]

I'd really recommend spending 5 minutes and reading [this](http://learnlayout.com/) to make sure you're up on using CSS to layout and position things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input and the link

Answer (score 2):

You should add

```
position: relative;
```

to the content container and then have the image positioned absolutely inside of that. The absolute positioning will then be based off that div, rather than the page.

Answer (score 0):

To position image outside of main div, use negative values on right:

```
 .image{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    right:-50px;
 }
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was using, and that positioning adjusts to how wide the window is which will cause the image to move around.

Comment: But you need set "relative" to position of main div.

Answer (score 0):

Like the people above have mentioned, it has to do with position relative. However, in order for it to remain stationary, you have to make a div that floats, and is not part of the normal content layout.

Here is an example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CSS Example</title>
    <style>
        body, html {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
        #wrapper {width: 960px;margin: 0 auto;}
        .floater {height: 100%; width: 100%;position: absolute;}
        .inner-float {position: relative; width: 1020px; margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;}
        .inner-float img {width: 150px; top: -10px; right: 0px;position: absolute;}
        .content {}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="floater">
        <div class="inner-float">
            <img src="./clipboard_icon.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

-e

Answer (score 0):

**if you can use percentages then here is a way to make an object REALLY stay put.  dont omit the body CSS**

```
<body style="padding:0; margin:0">

<div>

<div style="background-color:red; width:100%; height:300px; position:relative;">

<div style="background-color:green; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; margin: 10%;"></div>

</div></div>

</body>
```